# How can I use JMF functionality inside a java applet?

Tags: java, applet, wav, jmf

How can I use JMF to compress .wav file inside a java applet without requiring any installation?

Comment: *"How can I use JMF to compress .wav file inside a java applet"*  The same way you would do it in a desktop application of a command line app. *"..without requiring any installation?"*  If it can be done using the core Java version, add the relevant Jar to the applet's run-time class-path.  If it requires the enhanced version with the natives, it becomes trickier, but can be deployed using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: BTW - Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to just **compress** the file to make it *smaller*? Zipping it might work. Or are  you trying to change the file *type*?

Comment: *"Zipping it might work."*  No, it probably won't.  Media formats are typically highly compressed.  Zip compression does nothing for them - except to **add** a few bytes to indicate 'sorry, could not do anything with this file'.

Comment: *"wav to mp3 or , ogg vorbise or Fact format"*  JMF does not have the ability to encode MP3 (although it can *decode* it) & cannot handle the other two formats at all.

Comment: i have an exemple can convert from wav to mp3 using JMF

Comment: first i would like to thank you for your reactions .. the problem is that i want this applet(audio recording / compressing ) work in (linux, windows and mac) so i need a solution pure java without requiring any installation